# Understanding How DelayMS Function Works With PIC18F Microcontroller

Tags: c, delay, pic

I am trying to use a PIC18F45K22 to flash an LED on for a second, then off for a second, repeating indefinitely. The code incorporates a delay function that keeps the PIC busy for one second but I am not sure how it works (it was done through trial-and-error.) To achieve a 1 second delay, tWait should equal 125,000. I am using a 8MHz MCU clock frequency with PLL disabled. I know that 8MHz is 125nSec but after that, I am stuck. Can anyone please explain to me how it works? I've been at it for a few hours and it's driving me bonkers.

```
#define SYSTEM_FREQUENCY        (8000000) // 8MHz

// Prototype Function
void delayS(unsigned int sec);

void main()
{
     // Sets RA0 to output...
     TRISA.RA0 = 0;

     do
     {
       // Turns RA0 off...
       LATA.RA0 = 0;
       delayS(1);
       // Turns RA0 on...
       LATA.RA0 = 1;
       delayS(1);
     } while(1); // Repeat...
}

// My attempt at writing the function...
void delayS(unsigned int sec)
{
     unsigned long  tWait, tStart;
     /*
          To achieve a 1 Second On 1 Second Off cycle, tWait should be 125,000.
          How? Why? 64 is arbitrary to achieve 125,000.
     */
     tWait = Sec*(SYSTEM_FREQUENCY/64);
     for(tStart = 0; tStart < tWait; tStart++);

}
```

Comment: if your processor can execute 8 million commands per second, then you have to let him do 8 million commands to wait a second. And you have to be sure that the compiler cannot optimize it away.

Comment: Firstly make sure that 8MHz is the real clock. For example in PIC16F84 you use a 8MHz crystal but the actual speed is 4MHz. Then do nothing for 8 million cycles. The for loop isn't accurate if you eg use `twait = 8000000`. Some instructions are more than 1 clock cycle and the for loop isn't one instruction. An accurate delay need writing it in assemply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock frequency is 8MHz, so there are 2.10^6 cycles per seconds since a cycle takes 4 clock ticks. Any assembly operation of the microcontroller takes at least one cycle. There is still a factor 16 to explain.

The factor 16 must correspond to one pass of the loop. Since unsigned long are used in this loop, it is not surprising that it takes a few operations. You will need to look at the assembly code to understand what is happening and get a precise count, like [here](http://www.pcbheaven.com/picpages/Instruction_Cycle_Duration_and_Programmable_Delays/).

If you are working with MPLAB and the xc8 compiler, there are some functions you can use, such as `Delay10KTCYx(unsigned char);`.

The microcontroller spends 99.99% of its time counting, wich is not critical if you flash leds. But, to use efficiently a pic, you will need to avoid these functions by using timers and interruptions. Have fun !

Comment: Ahhh, ok, so you are saying that delay functions are a waste of resources and interrupts should be used instead? That actually makes a lot of sense. As for the looping, it's not a mathematical function but rather a consequence of looping through an unsigned long? Thank you so much, you've saved me a lot of headache. Now onto interrupts!

Comment: So what are you going to do till the interrupt fires? Nothing. First time I have heard `delay functions are a waste`.

Comment: @valter : you are right as long as a pic is used to flash a led. Delay functions are useful to learn how to use a pic, at start of main, or once from time to time. As soon as some interruptions are on, which is common on microcontrollers, these delay functions become imprecise. And the time spent counting could be used for computations related to control engineering, sending data to UART, or the pic could save energy. If Omusashas's only aim is to flash leds, delays are alright and interrupts and timers are not required. But i guess his needs will soon drive him to interrupts and timers.

Comment: Of cource interrupts are a major part of microcontrolers and delay functions a minor one. There is no wait logic in microcontrolers. You have to "waste" cycles occasionally. You are right about efficiency. A good program doesn't stop to count cycles. But some times it is necessary.